# Is it good to have multiple inner joins in SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

[image]I have a table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Devices]
(
    [Device_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Series_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Start_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Room_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [No_Of_Ports] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [text] NULL
);
```

I want to show this table in a gridview, but instead of showing the `[Series_ID]` column, I want to show 3 columns `Series_Name`, `Brand_Name`, and `Type_Name` from another 3 columns, and instead of showing the `[Room_ID]` column, I want to show 3 columns `Site_Name`, `Floor_Name`, `Room_Name` from another 3 columns

I can do that by more than 6 inner joins. I am a beginner in SQL and I want to know is this right to have a lot of inner joins in one statement in point of performance?

[image]

Comment: Is it sqlserver ?

Comment: yes it is sqlserver

Comment: The number of joins depends a lot on how your other tables look and where said columns are located at.

Comment: Multiple joins is fine for SQL.  That is what it is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query explanation, I assume it will be 2 inner joins instead of 6.

If Series_Name, Brand_Name and Type_Name are in one table with **Series_Id** as **ForeignKey**, then you would need one join.

Similarly, If Site_Name, Floor_Name, Room_Name are in one table with **Room_ID** as ForeignKey, then you would need another innjer join.

Again, it is difficult to tell the exact number of joins without understanding table structure of the other referential tables.

Comment: I added a simple picture to my question  to describe the relation between columns , i hope it help

Comment: Based on the image, your query might have 6 joins. As long as we use proper indexes, primary key and foreign key for joins, it should not affect the performance. SQL server provides a performance monitor where you can see the cost of query. it is always good to try with a sample set of data.